# swap variables while running the automation script in next time

Tags: java, selenium, automation

i'm writing the automation scripts for forgot password scenario, i'm declaring two variable "oldpassword" and "newpassword".

For the first time running the scripts, before changing the password oldpassword is "123456" and after changing password with forgot password the newpassword is "654321". and i will check the login . it's should not be login with old password and login with new passwords this is working fine.

While running the script second time,now oldpassword is "654321" and i want to make newpassord as "123456", that means for the first time running the scripts old is old and new is new, but for next time running the scripts it has swap password like old is new and new is old , how to do this?

please help me

Comment: Could you share your code as well which have you tried to achieve this??

Comment: instead swapping why not always create a new password on the fly and just store that as old password?

Comment: @MrunalGosar: Creating new password is fine, but how to store old password in Scripts without using DB

Comment: Have u heard of serialization?. Serialize the password object the way u want before coming out of the programme and once u start next time read that serialized object back in the way u want

Comment: @MrunalGosar: i don't have much knowledge on Serialization, please guide me

Comment: to start with: check any of this links: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+serialization&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the program, you could have an if command to check if a file is created or not, if not, you could create a file.

So the first time you open the program, the if command is false, meaning it is the first time you opened the program, hence old is old.

Then the second time you open the program, since the file is already made, the if command shows true, hence new is old.

This code should work.

```
    some declarations...
    int Opened = 1;

        try {
String content = new Scanner(new File("AFile.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
//The file has not been opened
Opened = 0;
        }

if (Opened == 1) {
//new = old
} else {
old = old
}
```

Your program is kinda confusing thought, I hope I got the thinking right...

Comment: but for 3rd time ?

Comment: Wait... I kinda don't get it... so you don't only want first and second, but you want first, second, third..... and it keeps on swapping?! That would be a little harder...